# how to select subquery from temp table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have tmp table which collect union data from three tables and it is work correctly the problem start when try to select any column from this tmp table as subquery, but i want to do this because i will make calculation from tmp table results ,so how to do this

i see this error message

> [42S02][1146] Table 'projectdb.tmp' doesn't exist

the problem with this code

```
(SELECT stquantity ) AS SB
```

my code is

```
SELECT tmp.it_code,(SELECT tmp.stquantity ) AS SB
FROM (
  SELECT
    tm.it_code AS it_code,
    2          AS ts_type,
    (
      SELECT SUM(rrg1.rpog_quantity)
      FROM d_repo_returned rpr1, d_repo_returned_grid AS rrg1
      WHERE rrg1.rpog_send_main_id = rpr1.rpo_id
            AND rrg1.rpog_item_id = tm.it_id
            AND rpr1.rpo_returned_date <= 1457996475

    )          AS stquantity,
    (SELECT SUM(rrg2.rpog_quantity)
     FROM d_repo_returned rpr2, d_repo_returned_grid AS rrg2
     WHERE rrg2.rpog_send_main_id = rpr2.rpo_id
           AND rrg2.rpog_item_id = tm.it_id
           AND rpr2.rpo_returned_date <= 1459375315

    )          AS edquantity

  FROM d_repo_returned, d_repo_returned_grid, d_items AS tm
  WHERE rpog_send_main_id = rpo_id
        AND rpog_item_id = tm.it_id
  GROUP BY tm.it_code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ts.it_code AS it_code,
    3          AS ts_type,
    (
      SELECT SUM(stg1.sig_quantity)
      FROM d_send_items str1, d_send_items_grid AS stg1
      WHERE stg1.sig_send_main_id = str1.si_id
            AND stg1.sig_item_id = ts.it_id
            AND str1.si_send_date <= 1457996475

    )          AS stquantity,
    (SELECT SUM(stg2.sig_quantity)
     FROM d_send_items str2, d_send_items_grid AS stg2
     WHERE stg2.sig_send_main_id = str2.si_id
           AND stg2.sig_item_id = ts.it_id
           AND str2.si_send_date <= 1459375315

    )          AS edquantity
  FROM d_send_items str, d_send_items_grid stg, d_items AS ts
  WHERE stg.sig_send_main_id = str.si_id
        AND stg.sig_item_id = ts.it_id
  GROUP BY ts.it_code
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    di.it_code             AS it_code,
    1                      AS ts_type,
    (SELECT SUM(di1.it_quantity)
     FROM d_items di1
     WHERE di1.it_code = di.it_code AND di1.it_date <= 1457996475
     GROUP BY di1.it_code) AS stquantity,
    (SELECT SUM(di2.it_quantity)
     FROM d_items di2
     WHERE di2.it_code = di.it_code AND di2.it_date <= 1459375315
     GROUP BY di2.it_code) AS edquantity
  FROM d_items di
  GROUP BY di.it_code
) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line (SELECT tmp.it_code,(SELECT stquantity ) AS SB)
to

```
SELECT it_code, stquantity AS SB
```

This is what I could understand from your query. :)

Comment: it is not working the problem is i want to select result from tmp table before creating it

Comment: you dont understand me correctly , i waaaaant subquery